# How do I match a string which contains a specific string using regex lazily?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I would like to match a string using regex in python which contains a specific string (lazy match) but haven't figured out how to do so.

For instance, in the following example, how do I return just `'<tag1>some text<tag2>some other text</tag2><tag1>'`
and not the whole string

```py
#!/bin/python3
import re
pattern = r'(<([a-zA-Z0-9]+?)\b[^>]*>.*?<tag2>some other text</tag2>.*?</\2>)'
text = '<root> <tag1>some text<tag2>some other text</tag2></tag1> </root>'
print(re.search(pattern, text, re.DOTALL).groups(0))
```

The code above prints `<root> <tag1>some text<tag2>some other text</tag2></tag1> </root>` when I want it to print `<tag1>some text<tag2>some other text</tag2></tag1>`
Of course, all of this assuming that there can be any tag in the place of `tag1`

Comment: It might be better to use an xml parser. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, for my use case, it is unsuitable.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the solution is quite simple,here's the regex that works:

`.*(<([a-zA-Z0-9]+?)\b[^>]*>.*?<tag2>some other text</tag2>.*?</\2>).*`